# My discord bot isn't turning on I think it is because of a Cogs error

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main (1)\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main>py main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main (1)\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cogs.ticket_commands import Ticket_Command
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main (1)\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main\cogs\ticket_commands.py", line 31, in <module>
    class Ticket_Command(commands.Cog):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main (1)\Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot-main\cogs\ticket_commands.py", line 47, in Ticket_Command
    @commands.slash_command(name="ticket")
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'slash_command'
```

I don't know how to fix it and when i try to install Cogs doing pip install Cogs it doesn't work it says:

```
Collecting Cogs
  Using cached Cogs-0.4.4.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:286: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The namespace_packages parameter is deprecated, consider using implicit namespaces instead (PEP 420).
        warnings.warn(msg, SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning)
      error in Cogs setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried re-installing python but it still doesn't work.

Here is the code so you can help me

```
#Version: 1.7
#GitHub: https://github.com/Simoneeeeeeee/Discord-Select-Menu-Ticket-Bot
#Discord: discord.gg/ycZDpat7dB

import discord
import json
from discord import *
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from cogs.ticket_system import Ticket_System
from cogs.ticket_commands import Ticket_Command

#This will get everything from the config.json file
with open("config.json", mode="r") as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

BOT_TOKEN = config["token"]  #Your Bot Token from https://discord.dev
GUILD_ID = config["guild_id"] #Your Server ID aka Guild ID  
CATEGORY_ID1 = config["category_id_1"] #Category 1 where the Bot should open the Ticket for the Ticket option 1
CATEGORY_ID2 = config["category_id_2"] #Category 2 where the Bot should open the Ticket for the Ticket option 2

bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot Logged | {bot.user.name}')
    richpresence.start()

#Bot Status, Counting all opened Tickets in the Server. You need to add/change things if you have more or less than 2 Categories
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def richpresence():
    guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    category1 = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=int(CATEGORY_ID1))
    category2 = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=int(CATEGORY_ID2)) #You need to add/change things if you have more or less than 2 Categories
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f'Tickets | {len(category1.channels) + len(category2.channels)}'))

bot.add_cog(Ticket_System(bot))
bot.add_cog(Ticket_Command(bot))
bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

That was main.py

```
import discord
import json
import chat_exporter
import io
import datetime
import sqlite3
from discord import *
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from cogs.ticket_system import MyView

#This will get everything from the config.json file
with open("config.json", mode="r") as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

TICKET_CHANNEL = config["ticket_channel_id"] #Ticket Channel where the Bot should send the SelectMenu + Embed
GUILD_ID = config["guild_id"] #Your Server ID aka Guild ID  

LOG_CHANNEL = config["log_channel_id"] #Where the Bot should log everything 
TIMEZONE = config["timezone"] #Timezone use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List and use the Category 'Time zone abbreviation' for example: Europe = CET, America = EST so you put in EST or EST ...

#This will create and connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

#Create the table if it doesn't exist
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket 
           (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, discord_name TEXT, discord_id INTEGER, ticket_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)""")
conn.commit()

class Ticket_Command(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Bot Loaded | ticket_commands.py ✅')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_bot_shutdown():
        cur.close()
        conn.close()


    #Slash Command to show the Ticket Menu in the Ticket Channel only needs to be used once
    @bot.tree.command(name="ticket")
    @has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def ticket(self, ctx):
        self.channel = self.bot.get_channel(TICKET_CHANNEL)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Support-Tickets", color=discord.colour.Color.blue())
        await self.channel.send(embed=embed, view=MyView(self.bot))
        await ctx.respond("Ticket Menu was send!", ephemeral=True)

    #Slash Command to add Members to the Ticket
    @commands.slash_command(name="add", description="Add a Member to the Ticket")
    async def add(self, ctx, member: Option(discord.Member, description="Which Member you want to add to the Ticket", required = True)):
        if "ticket-" in ctx.channel.name or "ticket-closed-" in ctx.channel.name:
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(member, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=False,
                                                embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True,
                                                external_emojis=True)
            self.embed = discord.Embed(description=f'Added {member.mention} to this Ticket <#{ctx.channel.id}>! \n Use /remove to remove a User.', color=discord.colour.Color.green())
            await ctx.respond(embed=self.embed)
        else:
            self.embed = discord.Embed(description=f'You can only use this command in a Ticket!', color=discord.colour.Color.red())
            await ctx.respond(embed=self.embed)

    #Slash Command to remove Members from the Ticket
    @commands.slash_command(name="remove", description="Remove a Member from the Ticket")
    async def remove(self, ctx, member: Option(discord.Member, description="Which Member you want to remove from the Ticket", required = True)):
        if "ticket-" in ctx.channel.name or "ticket-closed-" in ctx.channel.name:
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(member, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False,
                                                embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False,
                                                external_emojis=False)
            self.embed = discord.Embed(description=f'Removed {member.mention} from this Ticket <#{ctx.channel.id}>! \n Use /add to add a User.', color=discord.colour.Color.green())
            await ctx.respond(embed=self.embed)
        else:
            self.embed = discord.Embed(description=f'You can only use this command in a Ticket!', color=discord.colour.Color.red())
            await ctx.respond(embed=self.embed)

    @commands.slash_command(name="delete", description="Delete the Ticket")
    async def delete_ticket(self, ctx):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(LOG_CHANNEL)
        ticket_creator = int(ctx.channel.topic)

        cur.execute("DELETE FROM ticket WHERE discord_id=?", (ticket_creator,)) #Delete the Ticket from the Database
        conn.commit()

        #Create Transcript
        military_time: bool = True
        transcript = await chat_exporter.export(
            ctx.channel,
            limit=200,
            tz_info=TIMEZONE,
            military_time=military_time,
            bot=self.bot,
        )       
        if transcript is None:
            return
        
        transcript_file = discord.File(
            io.BytesIO(transcript.encode()),
            filename=f"transcript-{ctx.channel.name}.html")
        transcript_file2 = discord.File(
            io.BytesIO(transcript.encode()),
            filename=f"transcript-{ctx.channel.name}.html")
        
        ticket_creator = guild.get_member(ticket_creator)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f'Ticket is deliting in 5 seconds.', color=0xff0000)
        transcript_info = discord.Embed(title=f"Ticket Deleting | {ctx.channel.name}", description=f"Ticket from: {ticket_creator.mention}\nTicket Name: {ctx.channel.name} \n Closed from: {ctx.author.mention}", color=discord.colour.Color.blue())

        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
        #Checks if the user has his DMs enabled/disabled
        try:
            await ticket_creator.send(embed=transcript_info, file=transcript_file)
        except:
            transcript_info.add_field(name="Error", value="Couldn't send the Transcript to the User because he has his DMs disabled!", inline=True)
        await channel.send(embed=transcript_info, file=transcript_file2)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await ctx.channel.delete(reason="Ticket got Deleted!")
```

This is ticket_commands.
I need some help guys I already tried downgrading python to 3.9.13 and pycord to 2.0 doing pip install pycord==2.0

Comment: Downvoted because: [No code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and take a tour through [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your main.py, you have this specific line:

```
bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

This is used when you want to have prefixed commands in your bot. Looking at your cog, it seems you want to use slash commands instead which would work by changing that line with this one:

```
bot = discord.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

This makes it so your bot runs on slash commands only.

As you can see in [Pycord Documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/clients.html#discord.Bot.slash_command), `@slash_command` is present in discord.Bot class.

Try this and let me know if you run into any errors or need more explanation.